# Why cmake always build ".xcode" projects instead of .xcodeproj

Tags: xcode, cmake, xcode6

no matter which virson(2.8.12 3.0.2 3.1.0 or 3.4.1) cmake i use,it always build
".xcode" project instead of .xcdeproj.
Any ideas why the this happen?

Answer (score 0):

see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/XCODE_VERSION.html
I hava both xcode 6.3 and xcode 7.1.So I rename thers app name as "Xcode6.3" and "Xcode7.1",then cmake can't find "Xcode.app/Contents/version.plist".